# Обновление zabbix с версии 2.4 до 3.0

Tags: zabbix

Debian 7.1 x32
Обновляю Zabbix 2.4 из офф репозитория. 
В итоге после перезапуска службы zabbix-server в веб-панели вылетает сообщение:

```
Database error
The frontend does not match Zabbix database. Current database version
(mandatory/optional): 3000000/3000000. Required mandatory version: 2040000.
Contact your system administrator.
```

Как пофиксить? (без удаления данных из базы) 
UPD 
Залил исходники zabbix и скопировал php-файлы из директории frontend/php в директорию сервера. В итоге в логе nginx посыпались ошибки:

```
*1698 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addJsFile() on a non-object in /var/www/zabbix/setup.php on line 103" while reading response header from upstream, client: ***, server: ***.com, request: "GET /setup.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "***.com
```

Comment: А веб-панель-то обновили?

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install zabbix-frontend-php`
Изначальная ошибка фиксилась обновлением фронтэнда, теперь не знаю, что тебе делать.